# Azure pipeline system variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, system-variable

Do you know how to derive path for system variables $(System.ArtifactsDirectory) and $(Pipeline.Workspace) when deployment job running in Azure pipeline? e.g. If I enable debug, then in logs I can see below:

$(System.ArtifactsDirectory) -> D:\a\1\a
$(Pipeline.Workspace) -> D:\a\1

I am curious where configuration setting for the path, in my pc it is only with disk C: .

Answer (score 1):

These paths are relative to where the azure agent is installed. For example, if you were to install a self-hosted agent on your pc in the folder c:\azagent, then these directories would be in this folder

Comment: Thanks David! Further question would like to ask that as I only created a pipeline and ran it via https://dev.azure.com/org/project. Do you know how/where can I see the agent setting? I tried to search it via "Project Settings-> General -> Pipelines -> Agent pools/Parallel jobs/Settings". However, I cannot find it.

Comment: @stella I'm assuming you are using the classic UI to build pipelines? If so, edit the pipeline and you should see a section titled 'Agent job 1', click on this and in agent selection you will see agent pool (I'm guessing it'll be azure pipeline with a specification). If your pipelines are in yaml then check the file and you'll have a section with the pools defined within it